# Change column in Rails to be unique

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I know many similar questions have been asked before but I haven't found this question exactly (maybe it's just not possible).

So I have a Column_A in my Rails table (using MySQL). Recently we've had the need to enforce uniqueness on this column.

Is it possible to do a change on this column to make it unique?

The only other solution I came up with is to create a temporary unique column and shuffle everything around. Which would be a pain.

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure, why not you simply use validates_uniqueness_of :Column_A in your model?

Comment: `change_column :table_name, :column_name, :string, unique: true`

Comment: @PadmanabanGokula Can you explain the difference between `validates_uniqueness` and `unique`? I'd assume I can just do that with a migration?

Comment: validates_uniqueness is done by rails checking if the value already exists before it saves, but it's faillible to race conditions. On the other hand enforcing uniqueness by the db will guarantee it stays so

Comment: validates_uniqueness check for uniqueness for that value in the table column and if there is any duplicate it throw error and won't save. on the other hand unique? just check if it's unique value in the list or array. ('.uniq' in ActiveRecord get unique values from the column)

Comment: @PadmanabanGokula Does it hurt to do both?

Comment: The solution should be 2 steps, change your table with a migration as @PardeepDhingra suggested, and add validation in the model as i suggested. (.uniq is a query to get unique results nothing to do with your problem).

Comment: Thanks! Should I create a solution for this?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Simple two step process:

1: Create a migration

```
change_column :table_name, :column_name, :string, unique: true
```

2: Add validation in your model

```
validates_uniqueness_of :column_name
```

Comment: There is no database-level uniqueness (i.e. index created) with this

Answer (score 5):

You can add an index as such:

```
add_index :table_name, :column_name, unique: true
```

- rails 5.2